# Protractor tests fails when closing selenium-webdriver connection

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, appveyor, gulp-protractor

### Problem

I'm trying to get AppVeyor running some e2e tests using Protractor and Selenium-webdriver.

Everything works fine on my local machine, but when building and testing on AppVeyor protractor exits with code 1 due to a not-found method in the selenium-webdriver, it seems. I have tried to get some information on the error message, but my search didn't get me anywhere. Most of the result come from backend testing with Java.

Here is a snippet of the buildlog:

```
node_modules\.bin\gulp protractor
[08:37:23] Using gulpfile C:\projects\kitos\gulpfile.js
[08:37:23] Starting 'protractor'...
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.240.0.18:63619/wd/hub
.. 

Finished in 42.225 seconds
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures

C:\projects\kitos\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: Can't obtain updateLastError method for class com.sun.jna.Native
    at new bot.Error (C:\projects\kitos\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\projects\kitos\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:109:9)
    at C:\projects\kitos\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:379:20
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:/projects/kitos/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:1857:20)
    at [object Object].goog.defineClass.notify (C:/projects/kitos/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:2448:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:/projects/kitos/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:564:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:/projects/kitos/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/../webdriver/promise.js:553:15)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\projects\kitos\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
[08:38:13] 'protractor' errored after 50 s
[08:38:13] Error in plugin 'gulp-protractor'
Message:
    protractor exited with code 1
```

The selenium server is running, tests passes but when the server is about to shut down the error occurs.

### Setup

On build start I run `npm install` which in turn runs `node_modules\\.bin\\webdriver-manager update --standalone` as a postinstall script.

Protractor is run with a gulp task with the gulp-protractor plugin and the selenium standalone jar is defined in the protractor configuration as seen here:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',

    specs: ['Tests/**/*e2e.spec.js'],

    resultJsonOutputFile: 'results-protractor.json',

    allScriptsTimeout: 30000
};
```

The complete buildlog can be seen here: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Crevil/kitos/build/1.0.187
Apologizing for the noisy log. The deployment logging is very loud in the console and it is not configurable on AppVeyor afaict.

### Local log information

As mentioned, everything runs fine on my local machine. Here is a log of protractor running.

```
C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\kitos>gulp protractor
[09:54:58] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Git repos\kitos\gulpfile.js
[09:54:58] Starting 'protractor'...
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.5.153:16772/wd/hub
..

Finished in 5.241 seconds
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures

Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
[09:55:08] Finished 'protractor' after 10 s

C:\Users\BSO\Documents\Git repos\kitos>
```

Comment: Created [issue on protractors repository](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2728).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solve with the following parameter to the java runtime engine

```
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
        args: ['-Djna.nosys=true']
},
...
```

There are more details in the [protractor issue here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2728) and the [specific solution by Feodor Fitsner](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2728#issuecomment-182169617).